# Is it safe to initialize MS HANDLE to nullptr?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know using `nullptr` is more "typed". It can distinguish `pointer type` and `0` and works well in function overloading and template specialization.

So I am not sure whether it is safe to replace the `NULL` to `nullptr` in my old Win32 project in every `HANDLE`/`HWND`/`HINSTNACE` initialization usages?

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For handles that resolve to a pointer type you can use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. A good number of handle types are `typedef`'d as pointers so you shouldn't run into much problem.

This does **not** mean it is ok to use either `NULL` or `nullptr`. Some calls return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` which in VS2013 is defined as `((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1)` and relying on a null value to indicate an invalid/unopen handle may cause problems. For instance [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead of a zero or null value. All places in your code that assumes a null value indicates an unopened handle may cause problems.

Comment: Relevant [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Most handles (Kernel HANDLE, GDI handles, USER handles) are defined as pointers, but some (such as, IIRC, the CryptoAPI handles) are integers instead and thus wouldn't accept `nullptr` (or `NULL` in C code).

Comment: See MSDN's Old New Thing blog for more details: [Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/02/82639.aspx)

Comment: You guys definitely want to read this: **When MSDN says NULL, is it okay to use nullptr?** [reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180307-00/?p=98175)

Comment: Sorry but that article is a waste of time and can be summarized as "most people would probably prefer you to write NULL or nullptr.". This is not a compelling technical reason to follow the lemmings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. HWND, HANDLE, etc., most resolve to `void *`, so there's no reason not to use `nullptr`. That being said, it may be deemed more consistent with the API to use `NULL`, but it will not make a difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure some of them default to `struct HWND__ *` or something unless a `#define` is there.

Comment: @chris: That would be [`STRICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @MSalters, Ah, that sounds right now that you mention it.

Comment: And this would not work for `HANDLE` values that do not use `NULL`/`0` to indicate an *invalid* handle, like the `HANDLE` from `CreateFile()`. See MSDN's Old New Thing blog for more details: [Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/02/82639.aspx)